# how make my fixed td not moving out of my table when i'm scrolling

Tags: html, css

the JavaScript code just i wanted to limit my td moving over the `<h1>big titel</h1>`
but not working to stop the td moving down when I'm scrolling .
I need to make the td moving only in the table area , and don't allow the td to go out from the table when scrolling.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var header = document.getElementById("myExemple");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
  header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
#myExemple{
  position:fixed;

}
table{
  width:50%;
  height:250px;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table >
  <tr valign="top" id="myExemple">
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
</table>

<p><b>Note:</b> The valign attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.</p>
<p><b>Note:</b> The valign attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.</p>v<p><b>Note:</b> The valign attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.</p><p><b>Note:</b> The valign attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.</p>v<p><b>Note:</b> The valign attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.</p>v<p><b>Note:</b> The valign attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.</p>

<h1 class="header">
big titel !!!
</h1>
<p><b>Note:</b> The valign attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.</p>v<p><b>Note:</b> The valign attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.</p><p><b>Note:</b> The valign attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.</p>
<p><b>Note:</b> The valign attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.</p>v<p><b>Note:</b> The valign attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.</p><p><b>Note:</b> The valign attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.</p><p><b>Note:</b> The valign attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.</p>v<p><b>Note:</b> The valign attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.</p><p><b>Note:</b> The valign attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question above as opposed to linking to it in a jsfiddle offline where it might disappear. That will help you get an answer and preserve the question/answer long term.

Comment: thanks for the comment but i added the link in the first comment : https://jsfiddle.net/speedatome/zjewshk7/15/

Comment: my point was the link is great but the coffee needs to be posted directly on stackoverflow if you really want help.

Comment: ok @SteveB i will add the code in the question now !

Answer (score 0):

you may want to make use of CSS' property `sticky`. the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning) provides an example that would be applicable in your case.

in your CSS, you could change your ruleset as follows:

```
#myExemple {
  position: sticky;
  top: -1px;
}
```

`Sticky` will treat the element as `position:relative` while the parent container is visible *and* and isn't scrolled. Once you start scrolling, it will behave like `position:absolute` ... but relative to the parent container. And once the element is out of the view port, it goes back to relative. So ... it's ... "sticky".

By doing this, you no longer need JavaScript. Support for `sticky` [is pretty good](https://caniuse.com/css-sticky), too. Despite what Caniuse says, I tested this in Firefox (my default browser) and had no issues.

If you want to get around the issue that Chrome has with applying `position:sticky` to `<tr>`, you have two options

1. set the `<tr>`'s `display` to something other than `table-row`. like `inline-block`, `inline-flex`, or similar.
2. make a class called `sticky` and apply it to the `<th>`.

[In this example](https://jsfiddle.net/Paceaux/m6x8b2ks/) I get a scrolling header with option 2.

Comment: look at this example and tell me if this is your intent: https://jsfiddle.net/Paceaux/m6x8b2ks/

Comment: This solution will not work on chrome because of a known bug with position sticky not working on thead and tr elements. Change `#myExemple` to `#myExemple th` to fix. https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

Comment: take another look at my example. instead of an `id`, I applied a `class` to the `<th>` elements. works in Chrome and FF.

Comment: @paceaux look at this exemple and tell me if any way to make div "Month" moving down only in the td tag when i'm scrolling : https://jsfiddle.net/speedatome/y3k5gap4/13/

Comment: i tried to make the position fixed and look what i got :) ===> https://jsfiddle.net/speedatome/y3k5gap4/18/

Comment: hey, if I helped get you to a solution, be so kind as to upvote ;)

Comment: ok @paceaux ! it's my first question in stackoverflow , i still don know how it works here ! bu i will upvote for you ! thank you again :)